# How to prevent net scan?

Tags: iptables, portscan

i have major issues with server provider due to net scan on local IP, sometimes on public ips too.

how can i prevent this and/ or identify the user ?

Comment: You won't be able to easily identify things like this - if you are getting port scanned from *inside* the network you have a compromised system somewhere; if you are scanned at the public IP address not much you can do either

Comment: i can identify via tcpdump that the scan is being performed from my ip and the ports, but cannot identity the external ip connected to server and doing that. running a office vpn on it...bet it's one of the users but can't identify which

Comment: Wait so the scan origin point is *your computer*?

Comment: yes....the scan is made from my server to provider's server mainly. can't identify who/how this is done. 

this is why i find trouble to prevent it.

Comment: I'm confused... what's VPNing to where?  Is it your server or your computer running the VPN that's doing the probing?  If it's the server and it's on the VPN, and that is YOUR server and not your workplace's server, I'd say your server may be compromized and you should stop using it

Comment: Basically, we need more details.  Is your computer itself doing the VPN?  Is a server?  Is your computer actually doing the scanning?  Is a server doing the scanning?  We have no details that we actually need to answer this

Comment: 1. running vpn on a ubuntu server for several friends 
2. not my personal PC
3. getting notifications form data center that i do netscans
4. can't figure out how/who this is done and how to monitor
5. the netscan is performed on local IPs of the data center from my server

Comment: Then I would say either your server is compromised or your "friends" are using the VPN to port scan.  Nothing in Ubuntu does network scanning by default (except Avahi but that should be off by default on servers), and if anything is then it's likely a compromised machine.

Comment: how to i avoid netscan of local IPs ? a simple drop in iptables on a range is enough ?

Comment: just blokced in the end all possbile RFC local ips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply blocked in the end RFC 1918 in iptables. Worked like a charm

Comment: Would you provide the full solution here please? How did you enter this rule in iptables? Thanks

Comment: these are the RFC tables 

    10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
     172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
     192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)


iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10/8 -j DROP